# xlwings parsing excel data take a long time

Tags: xlwings

I have an excel with many tabs and lots of data on them. I replaced the vba code with Python it works well, however, it take a long time to read excel data. Is there something I can do to improve the performance ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious way to speed things up is to minimize the cross-application calls from Python to Excel. An example (from the docs): It is always more efficient to do `Range('A1').value = [[1,2],[3,4]]` than `Range('A1').value = [1, 2]` and `Range('A2').value = [3, 4]`